# How to add script or stylesheet in a particular document or layout in DocPad?

Tags: docpad

How can I add a stylesheet or script in a particular document or layout in DocPad ?

If I use something like:

```
<%- @getBlock('scripts').add(["/local.js"]).toHTML() %>
```

The script will be added where the content or layout is rendered.

But is it possible to add scripts that are added at the end with the other scripts declared on the default layout? Or in the `<head>` in the case of a stylesheet or a `<meta>`?

In WordPress, you would use `wp_head` et `wp_footer` hooks to do that. Is there some kind of equivalent mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the following what you're after?

```
<%- @getBlock('scripts').add(@site.scripts or []).add(@document.scripts or []).add(['/whatever/else.js']).toHTML() %>
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems easier like this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've defined a helper function in `docpad.coffee`:

```coffeescript
dpBlock: (type) ->
  blocks = []
  blocks = blocks.concat @site[type] if @site[type] and Array.isArray @site[type]
  blocks = blocks.concat @document[type] if @document[type] and Array.isArray @document[type]
  @getBlock(type).add(blocks).toHTML() if blocks.length > 0
```

Then I just have to define an Array of scripts, styles, and meta at `@site` and/or `@document` level, and use the helper function in the default layout.

Comment: I think the block check above can actually cause problems. Because, there might be no explicit scripts but some still injected by a plugin (e.g. livereload). So, if no custom scripts are defined, livereload code will not load either.